# How to fix a black screen after faulty NVIDIA display driver install on 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, multiple-monitors, 20.04, crash

I decide to installed the NVIDIA  driver to see if I could resolve an issue I have been having with multiple monitors not working. Really hope I can find a solution to the crazy strange zoom when attaching external monitors.

A warning appeared and after a reboot the display driver daemon stopped loading and my computer hung. Lunch time, during work!!! And so begun my research on how to resolve the hanging computer.

I'm using 20.04 and it has stopped booting after installing a screen driver am unable to get to a recover screen. The most I can get to is Grub.

All the recommended Key combinations didn't work and posts resulted in very little outcome.

I am unable to get to a recover screen. The most I can get to is Grub.

That's what it appeared like. I have answered the question below, however still do not have a solution to using multiple screens. When connected, the screens are mismatched sizes. Looks crazy and not very helpful!

[image: Failed To load Screen Drivers and Ubuntu isn't booting]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a post to help others who may be as confused as I was. The computer appears to crashed after installing a NVIDIA driver.

## **Pre**

The laptop has NVIDIA display and USB-C + HDMI ports. The screens are mismatched sizes. Looks crazy!

***Option1:*** The laptop has mini zoomed in screen and text or

***Option 2:*** The external screens have giant zoomed in text. Working from home, nobody sees this, so I can use Linux, otherwise I might look like quite the fool with the 'Norms' at work.

## **Crash**

I decide to installed the NVIDIA proprietary driver to see if I could resolve this issue. A warning appeared and after a reboot the display driver daemon stopped loading. (day 1 - friday)

## Red Herrings

After researching (friday night), I thought that I could only get to grub. All the suggested posts <kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>functions keys</kbd> did not seem to load a recovery option as described with this screen driver failure scenario,  or perhaps it's 20.04 ...I thought.

(Sat morning) After much research, I thought that it might be the <kbd>fn</kbd> key was locked on the laptop and maybe I should hold down <kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> . I finally got to a place where the boot process stopped without a complete failure. Alternatively, it's always been working and it me and the fact that the display driver is not loading. It just appears as if everything has failed.

The load process ended with many green [OK] lines appearing and just appears to have hung. I begun trying random key combinations as there must be some logical key combination that could get me to "level up"

## Finally

After the Green [OK]s had finished loading
I tried <kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>

Finally!! a login command prompt.

Now I can try all those posts about uninstalling and installing the screen drivers via the command line

## Handy Commands

`sudo ubuntu-drivers list`

`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`  Lists recommended drivers

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (This command stack tracked for me so did the below command as it was the recommended)

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`

`sudo reboot`

Bingo!!

***I still don't have a solution around the multi screens I am trying to run. Weird external zooming*** Maybe one day I will be paid to code screen drivers.